# finding maximum number in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

this is my practice before my upcoming test, I'm trying to make the user input a number. And all elements in array1 that is below the user's number, will be put in a new ArrayList.
and then I'm trying to print only the highest number in that ArrayList. If the user input is lower than all number in array1, it will return -1. 
here is my code, however, when I put 920, it still returns -1,  I think there's something wrong with my code to find highest number in ArrayList. Can you guys please tell me what is wrong?

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static int[] array1 = {900, 885, 989, 1000, 1500, 1243, 999, 915};

public static int blabla(int[] a, int b) {

Integer d = -1;
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { // this is to find all numbers in array1 that is below user's number, and add it to the ArrayList
        if (b > array1[i]) {
        al.add(array1[i]);
        } // if
    } // for

    outerloop: // and this function below is to find maximum number in ArrayList
    for (int g = (al.size()-1); g == 0; g--) {
                for (int j = 0; j <=(g-1); j++) {
                    if (al.get(j) > al.get(g)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(j == (g-1)) {
                        if (al.get(g) > al.get(j)){
                            d = al.get(g);
                            break outerloop;
                        }
                    }
                } //for^2
    } // for
return d;
} // priceisright
```

Comment: In your first loop, you are looping over the elements of the newly created ArrayList, but this newly created ArrayList is empty, so this loop will not even run. Do you mean instead to loop over the elements of the passed Array?

Comment: It would be much easier for you to understand your own code if you gave your variables and methods a meaningful name, and if you delegated to methods instead of putting everything in a single one. You should also think again about your algorithm. Why do you need two nested loops to find the maximum element in a list? All you need to do is looping through every element and compare each of them with the current maximum. If bigger, then change the value of the current maximum. Also, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: You could find the maximum number more efficiently (O(n^2) isn't exactly efficient.. ). Why not sort it in the first place?

Comment: @Kon What do you mean? the new ArrayList was empty yes, that's why I fill it with all numbers from array1 that is below the user's number (al.add(a1[i])) or did I miss something?

Comment: @JBNizet What I was trying to do with my code was, the variable 'g' is the last element in ArrayList, and variable j is the first element, that's how I compare it one by one, I don't know what is wrong though

Comment: @TheLostMind sorry, what do you mean by (O(n^2) ? yah, I can google how to sort it, but I need to know what is wrong with my code :/

Comment: Here's how I would find the tallest person in a long queue of persons. If the queue is empty, there is no tallest person. If not, I'll assume the first is the tallest. Then I'll compare it to the second. If the second is taller, he/she becomes the tallest. Then I compare the third with the current tallest, etc. etc. until the end of the queue. Sorting the list to find the maximum is a bad idea. It modifies the list which doesn't need to be modified, and it's O(n*log(n)) instead of being O(n).

Comment: 2 for loops are not necessary.. Your approach of copying the numbers smaller than the given number into a different arraylist can be done as @JBNizet says. With one for loop.

Comment: @Rei +1 just for your efforts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static int[] array1 = {900, 885, 989, 1000, 1500, 1243, 999, 915};

public static int blabla(int[] a, int b) {

Integer d = -1;
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**At this point, a1 is an empty array, so a1.length = 0, this loop never gets executed.**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) { 
        // this is to find all numbers in array1 that is below user's number, 
        // and add it to the ArrayList
        if (b > a1[i]) {
            al.add(a1[i]);
        } // if
    } // for
```

**a1 is still empty there, the second loop won't do anything either.**

```
    // and this function below is to find maximum number in ArrayList
    outerloop: 
    for (int g = (al.size()-1); g == 0; g--) {
                for (int j = 0; j <=(g-1); j++) {
                    if (al.get(j) > al.get(g)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(j == (g-1)) {
                        if (al.get(g) > al.get(j)){
                            d = al.get(g);
                            break outerloop;
                        }
                    }
                } //for^2
    } // for
return d;
} // priceisright
```

What about this:

```
    // Finds the greater value in values that is below maximum.
    // Returns -1 if none is found. 
    public static int blabla(int[] values, int maximum) {
      int best_value = -1;
      for (int value : values) {
        if (value < maximum && value > best_value) {
          best_value = value;
        }
      }

      return best_value;
    }
```

You can replace `int[] values` by `List<Integer> values` if your values are in an ArrayList.

Comment: That's way better. No need for an ArrayList, just loop through the array, finding the maximum value that is below the user input.

Comment: I think he wants to store the values under the input, why would he have done that way if not?

Comment: I estimated (Rei feel free to correct me) the intermediate ArrayList was just a temporary storage to split the operation in two simple ones (extract the valid values then find the max), which is a good way to build things. Doing both in a simple loop is possible in that case and makes a shorter and faster algorithm but this is not always the case and spitting a complex algorithm in small pieces is usually a good approach. The initial code could work with minor fixes, that's why I pointed the problems it had.

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux actually, 'a1' is array1, I edited it when I paste it here so it's more readable, but I forgot to edit that a1, so people mistook it with ArrayList 'al'. sorry about that :/

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
 Collections.max(arrayList);
```

To know more about read  [Javadoc for Collection.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: I guess he want to write his own max/sort, not to use library functions.

Comment: also, this function wouldn't actually help the OP achieve - "And all elements in array1 that is below the user's number, will be put in a new ArrayList"

Comment: that works, thanks :D since the very first loop already put only intended number into the new arraylist. I would like to know what's wrong with my code, tho :/

Comment: That does not really answer the question: what was wrong with the initial code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an `ArrayList` you can check fro maximum with linear time by,

```
public static Integer getMaximum(List<Integer> coll) {
  if (coll == null) {
    return null;
  }
  Integer i = coll.get(0);
  for (int t = 1; t < coll.size(); t++) {
    Integer v = coll.get(i);
    if (v != null && v > i) {
      i = v;
    }
  }
  return i;
}
```

Or, you could change that to a `SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();` then the maximum element is always `set.last();`

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your two for loops by this one:

```
        for (int g = 0; g <=(al.size()-1); g++) { //for each value in your new array
            d = (al.get(g)>d)? al.get(g):d; //is current value higher than previous? if not keep old one
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to find the max in an array or arrayList (or any collection actually) without using built in methods such as .max

```
Int currentMax = 0

For (int i = 0; i < al.length; i++)
{
  If al[i] > currentMax
  {
    CurrentMax = al[i]
  }
}
```

Answered this from my phone so I apologize for bad indents, but you get the idea :)

Comment: You have to hope that the list doesn't only contain negative numbers.

Comment: I did think of that... But simply start currentMax at some negative number you are sure you cant beat... -999999999999 should work (change to a double as well before someone comments on that too)

Comment: Why not set currentMax to the first element of the list instead? That would be correct always. And the same algorithm could be used for any kinf of list, not only for lists of numbers.

Comment: Yes i suppose that would work too - not sure why I didn't think of that. haha. But the concept is what the OP is after :)